# Why is my Kotlin function that loads images from firebase storage so slow?

Tags: android, firebase, image, kotlin, firebase-storage

I am quite new to programming and for this app I am using Kotlin in Android Studio. I have a function that loads stored images from firebase storage, both images that are available to all users and also "private" images. It works fine but it takes about 20-30 seconds to load images. I think it should be able to fix faster?

This is how the function looks today:

```
private fun listStoredImages() = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        try {
            val userImages = imageRef.child(uid).listAll().await()
            val publicImages = imageRef.child("UploadedPictures").listAll().await()

            // Loads private images from storage
            for (image in userImages.items) {
                val url = image.downloadUrl.await()
                userImageUrl.add(url.toString())

            }   // loads public images from storage
            for (publicImage in publicImages.items) {
                val publicUrl = publicImage.downloadUrl.await()
                userImageUrl.add(publicUrl.toString())
            }
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                recyclerView.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                Toast.makeText(this@UserCreateAndEditActivity, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
```

The declaration of imageRef:

```
val imageRef = Firebase.storage.reference
```

I don't know if it makes any difference but I am using grid to show the images. Like this:

```
private var gridLayoutManager: GridLayoutManager? = null
```

on create:

```
gridLayoutManager =
            GridLayoutManager(applicationContext, 3, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
        imageAdapter = ImageAdapter(this, userImageUrl)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = gridLayoutManager
        recyclerView.adapter = imageAdapter
```

Any idea how I can make it faster?

Comment: How many images are you loading?

Comment: I guess your coroutine scope uses 1 thread to load both public and private images and switching between 2 different requests. That may be the problem

Comment: @Steyrix It is about 20-30 images. Thanks I will try using 2 different threads :-)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I was only updating my View with

```
withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                recyclerView.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
```

after all the image urls where done loading.
After I added the notifyDataSetChanged in the for loops after each image loaded it was much quicker.

Comment: You can actually accept your own answer so the question will be closed :)